# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register() in /home/jef2mcggxor1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 69

Tags: error

I am trying to run some of my code by each time, i am getting this error, i am using the lates version of php.
i replaced my caused as per the error; from this

function __autoload($class_name) {
$class_name = strtolower($class_name);
$path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
if(file_exists($path)){
require_once($path);
}else{
die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
}

to this

function spl_autoload_register($class_name) {
$class_name = strtolower($class_name);
$path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
if(file_exists($path)){
require_once($path);
}else{
die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
}
then got another error message

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register() in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\marimar\includes\functions.php on line 37
Any help on how to solve this.
here is the complete code: https://www.mediafire.com/file/l1hwccshou9dhjh/functions.php/filet

Comment: Can you share code of that class?

Comment: Same issue for me..is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are simply trying to create / redeem a function with the name of an existing native function :

function spl_autoload_register($class){require_once"{$class}.class.php";}
If the intention is to use spl_autoload_register , the correct would be to do this:

function meu_autoloader($class) {
require_once"{$class}.class.php";
}

spl_autoload_register('meu_autoloader');
Or use closure (PHP anonymous function) directly:

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
require_once"{$class}.class.php";
});